# Frame Redirect in C#

Tags: c#, iis-7, httpcontext, ihttpmodule

I would like to execute a frame redirect in C# from my managed module for the IIS 7.

When I call `context.Response.Redirect(@"http://www.myRedirect.org");`the correct page is shown but also the address is shown in the browser. And that is exactly what I do not want.

So I want something like:

```
private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = app.Context;

    // make a frame redirect if a specified page is called
    if (context.Request.ServerVariable["HTTP_REFERER"].Equals(@"http://www.myPage.org/1.html"))
    {
        // perform the frame redirect here, but how?
        // so something like
        context.Response.Redirect(@"http://www.myRedirect.org");
        // but as I said that doesn't redirect as I want it to be
    }
}
```

Any ideas about that?

**EDIT:**
I tried the example, so I have:

```
private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = app.Context;

    // make a frame redirect if a specified page is called
    if (context.Request.ServerVariable["HTTP_REFERER"].Equals(@"http://www.myPage.org/1.html"))
    {
        // perform the frame redirect here, but how?
        context.Response.Write(@"<html>");
        context.Response.Write(@"<head>");
        context.Response.Write(@"</head>");
        context.Response.Write(@"<frameset rows=""100%,*"" framespacing=""0"" frameborder=""NO"" border=""0"">");
        context.Response.Write(@"<frame src=""http://www.myRedirect.org"" scrolling=""auto"">");
        context.Response.Write(@"</frameset>");
        context.Response.Write(@"<noframes>");
        context.Response.Write(@"<body>Some text...");
        context.Response.Write(@"</body>");
        context.Response.Write(@"</noframes>");
        context.Response.Write(@"</html>");
    }
}
```

But that also doesn't correctly redirect. I still have the redirect address shown in my browser. So any other idea?

EDIT:
I obviously made a mistake. The code above works and does what I want. It first didn't work because my redirect url was doing something unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a [frame redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Frame_redirects) you need to send back the HTML code containing a frameset with a single frame, with it's source set to http://www.myRedirect.org.  As far as the server and browser is concerned no redirect has happened - it's just received some HTML code.

Performing a `Response.Redirect` will, as you've observed, cause the browser to make a fresh new request to the new page, showing the user the new address in the title bar.  It's typically used for when a page actually changes its address, but the owners still want it reachable from the original URL as well.

**EDIT**: HTML frame redirect sample: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Frame_redirects

Comment: There's a good example in the Wikipedia article (linked on the words "frame redirect" in my post) of the HTML code to send, but I've never written a server module so I don't know how you'd do that.  Maybe with `Response.Write(... HTML code ...)` ?